# SQL delete a specific row among several identical foreign keys but has the oldest date on it

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete a row among several others that have identical foreign keys, but I need to delete the oldest one.

I don't know the oldest date. Therefore I need to check with all the others rows first I think.

```
 DELETE FROM SOMEWHERE WHERE PROD_ID = 'me' AND DATE ???;");
```

Data types are:

INT for foreign key.
TIMESTAMP for date(to select the oldest date)

I'm using MYSQL.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your code attempt.

Comment: So say there are 3 rows with thesame foreign key but different dates would you want to delete the oldest one only or preserve just the most recent row?

Comment: I added how far I got

Comment: delete the oldest one thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM SOMEWHERE WHERE PROD_ID = 'me' ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will get you the oldest date and delete it. You sort it based on your date field, in descending order and you just delete the first (oldest).

Comment: Ahh thanks thats easy, I didnt know you could do that by using DESC, I though you need a more complicated query.

Comment: Glad i helped. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please accept it.

Comment: if you could give me a like that would help me too since im new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Please note this is a **non-standard** SQL extension. It's great for this case, but if you switch to another database you'll need to use another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE A FROM SOMEWHERE A JOIN (SELECT PROD_ID, MIN(DATE) OLDEST_DATE
FROM SOMEWHERE
GROUP BY PROD_ID) B ON A.PROD_ID=B.PROD_ID AND A.DATE=B.OLDEST_DATE
WHERE A.PROD_ID='me';
```

See a working [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/122ba1/1).

Answer (score 0):

A subquery in the `WHERE` clause should work. Try something like:

```
DELETE FROM SOMEWHERE A WHERE A.PROD_ID = 'me' AND A.DATE = (
   SELECT MIN(B.DATE) FROM SOMEWHERE B WHERE A.PROD_ID = B.PROD_ID)
```

This has the benefit of working for multiple PROD_IDs in case you are doing a batch of them instead of just the literal 'me'.